# Running time of lastIndexOf for an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the running time of `lastIndexOf` for `ArrayLists` in Java?

Comment: when any user gives you answer and if it suits your question then you should accept it by click on the  "tick" mark below the downvote icon which is the there in the left side of answer. This way you helps others to

Comment: @user963737 You should post your comment on my answer not on your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the average execution time is proportional to *number of elements*. That is, this method is an **O(n)** operation, where **n** is *number of elements*.